# Unable to delete anything in telegram

Tags: telegram

My question is that I am unable to delete any message or photo in a group chat.[image: Group chat pic 1]

[image: Group chat pic 2]

Answer (score 0):

EDIT 
It might be worth having a look at telegram today, they have announced some new features, including the unsed/delete anything.

Details are here: [Unsend Anything](https://telegram.org/blog/unsend-privacy-emoji#unsend-anything)

If you are in a channel, then the behaviour you have highlighted would be expected, you would be able to reach out to the creator and ask them to delete the message(s) or discuss being given access rights on the channel.

As per Telegram FAQ: 
The creator of a channel can broadcast messages, delete any messages, add members (the first 200 only), remove members, change the channel's name, profile image and link, as well as delete the channel completely. The creator can also add and remove administrators to help manage the channel.

Have a look at Telegram's website here for more information: [What can administrators do?](https://telegram.org/faq_channels#q-what-can-administrators-do)

Comment: but it is basic functionality to delete a message, why did they excluded this

Comment: @AvinashKumar 
That would be at the discretion of the creator of the channel.

Comment: It's a group not channel